# Rails migration index for joined tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using rails 3 and my production db is postgres on Heroku. How do I create a proper index for this query? I don't know how to create one for the inner join that's happening.

```
SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans" 
INNER JOIN "schedules" 
ON "plans".schedule_id = "schedules".id 
WHERE (("schedules".user_id = 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add an index on schedules.user_id:

```
add_index :schedules, :user_id
```

... and another index for plans by schedule:

```
add_index :plans, :schedule_id
```

Additionally, if you're trying to load all the schedules w/ associated plans you should probably use a left join:

```
select plans.*
  from schedules
  left join plans on plans.schedule_id = schedule.id
  where schedules.user_id = 4
```

I think the left join will be correct for what you want here.

Comment: Interesting, I was hoping there was a way to do a multi-column index or something. Thanks for this. The inner join is what I want though since plans must belong to a schedule.